# How to exclude column names from csv output in Oracle BI publisher

Tags: csv, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to create a comma delimited csv file for a downstream system. I created a data model in Oracle BI Publisher and need to produce a csv file output. I was able to do that, however the csv file output is printing the column names and the downstream system consuming this file cannot accept the column names, just the data below returned by the data model. Anyone aware of a solution to this? I haven't been able to find much on the internet regarding this and a clear solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As I'm new to BI publisher, I tried creating an RTF/etext template to map the data to as well. But as I've read online, it seems that csv outputs from BI publisher don't consider the template anyway, and just rely on the data model itself to produce the csv output.

Comment: You will have to modify your data model. 

https://community.oracle.com/customerconnect/discussion/543959/remove-column-header-in-bip-csv-output

Or use an eText template where you have more options, though that will take more time.